# Generators of Special Linear Groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, integer-lattices

Linear algebra and special-linear group experts please help:

I learn that in principle one can generate this $M$ matrix form the $B_1$ and $B_2$ matrix below. Here
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1& 0\\ -1& 1& 0\\ 0& 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
from:
$$
B_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0& 1\\ 1& 0& 0\\ 0& 1& 0 \end{pmatrix},
\text{ 
and   }\;\; 
B_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1& 0\\ 0& 1& 0\\ 0& 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

> **Question: How to generate $M$ from $B_1$ and $B_2$?** i.e. **So what is the exact expression to make $M=\dots B_1 \dots B_2$ as a product of $B_1$ and $B_2$ matrices?**

I learned the basics about those generators and SL(N,Z) from the book Coxeter and Moser on "**Generators and relations for discrete groups**" (published by Springer, 1957).

Thank you! :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but here is an exact expression:

$M=B_2B_1B_2B_1B_2^{-1}B_1^{-1}B_2^{-1}B_1B_2B_1$

also

$M=(B_2B_1^2)^2(B_2B_1)(B_1B_2)^{-2}$

The subgroup $H$ of $G$ generated by a set $X$ is the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ that contain $X$, so $H$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $X$. Since $X$ is a subgroup it is closed under inversion, and so must contain the inverses of every element of $X$. Hence one is generally allowed to use inverses of generators (or equivalently, both positive and negative powers). In this particular case, $B_1^3$ is the identity, so $B_1^{-1} = B_1^2$ and we can avoid inverses of $B_1$ if we don't mind multiplying by two copies of $B_1$. However, it does not appear that $B_2^{-1}$ can be written only using positive powers of $B_1$ and $B_2$ (I verified that any such expression has the powers adding up to more than $29$).

Comment: Dear Jack, +1, thank you, this is the thing. But I wonder whether one can also express $B_1^{-1}$ and $B_2^{-1}$ in terms of just $B_1$ and $B_2$? When we say that $B_1$ and $B_2$ can generate all SL(3,Z) does that mean just $B_1$ and $B_2$ alone?

Comment: (or am I wrong, we need to include $B_1^{-1}$ and $B_2^{-1}$?)

Comment: Thank you Jack. You are such an expert! If there is no better answer in a few days, yours are my top accepted answers! :o)

Comment: btw, Jack how do you find out the $M$ expression? :)

Comment: I just asked GAP to try all expressions in order of length and reported (a) the first one and (b) a "shorter" one due to factoring. Sometimes the first one is not the most helpful one, but I didn't see any helpful ones.

Comment: Sorry, clicked the wrong button and down voted instead of upvoting the answer.

Comment: Dear Jack, by saying "any such expression has the powers adding up to more than 22", you are claiming that $B_2^{-1}$ cannot be achieved by positive powers of $B_1$, $B_2$ for less than the power of 22. Yes?

Comment: Right, As in $B_1^{a_1} \cdot B_2^{a_2} \cdot B_1^{a_3} \cdots = B_2^{-1}$ with $a_i \geq 0$ implies $\sum a_i \geq 22$ (27 now). I conjecture there are no values of $a_i$ that work, but all I've shown is that no small values of $a_i$ work.

Comment: Dear Jack, b.t.w. I failed to install GAP so far, perhaps you don't mind to assist me with GAP again?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748799/matrix-linear-algebra-generators; I tried by hand and generate a order of the power 20 expression, but I wonder whether there is a shorter expression from GAP? Thanks so much.

Comment: Dear Jack, here is a new one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198702/expression-from-generators-of-special-linear-groups-ii