# Matrix linear algebra generators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Linear algebra and special-linear group experts please help:

It is known that in principle one can generate this $C$ matrix form the $A$ and $B$ matrix below. Here
$$
C=\begin{pmatrix} 0& -1& 0\\ 1& 0& 0\\ 0& 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
from:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0& 1\\ 1& 0& 0\\ 0& 1& 0 \end{pmatrix},
\text{ 
and   }\;\; 
B=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1& 0\\ 0& 1& 0\\ 0& 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

> **Question: How to generate $C$ from $A$ and $B$?** i.e. **So what is the exact expression to make $C=\dots A \dots B$ as a product of $A$ and $B$ matrices?** As the shortest expression as possible.

p.s. I manage to generate a $C$ from a combined power of $A$ and $B$ with the exponent of 20s. I wonder what is the shortest expression?

Thank you! :o)

Comment: What expressions are allowed?

Comment: any power of A, B, B^{-1}; only the matrix multiplication. Such as $C=ABAB^{-2}$. I suppose you cannot generate $B^{-1}$ from A and B. (But it is not the case for $A^{-1}=A^2$.) thanks~ :o)

Comment: maybe someone have interests to answer my new question here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751167/counting-problem-very-interesting-modular-n-algebraic-eqs-for-combinatorics; :0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions $A^{n_1} B^{n_2} A^{n_3} \cdots = C$ with $\sum |n_i|$ minimal are exactly the following:

- $B^{-1}AB^{-1}AB^{-1}A^{-1}BABAB^{-1}$
- $B^{-1}ABABA^{-1}B^{-1}AB^{-1}AB^{-1}$
- $B^{-1}A^{-1}BA^{-1}B^{-1}AB^{-1}A^{-1}BA^{-1}B^{-1}$
- $B^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}BABA^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}$

These are found by trying all such expressions ordered by $\sum |n_i|$.

Comment: you must be a rubik cube master!

Comment: Wow. How did you find these?

Comment: Math masters - maybe you can help on answering this algebra and matrix Rep question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752551/what-is-this-algebra-a-generalized-2-times-2-pauli-matrices-or-4-times-4. Thanks.